# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, unicode

```
def main():
    client = ##client_here
    db = client.brazil
    rio_bus = client.tweets
    result_cursor = db.tweets.find()
    first = result_cursor[0]
    ordered_fieldnames = first.keys()
    with open('brazil_tweets.csv','wb') as csvfile:

        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames = ordered_fieldnames,extrasaction='ignore')
        csvwriter.writeheader()
        for x in result_cursor:
            print x
            csvwriter.writerow( {k: str(x[k]).encode('utf-8') for k in x})

        #[ csvwriter.writerow(x.encode('utf-8')) for x in result_cursor ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Basically the issue is that the tweets contain a bunch of characters in Portuguese. I tried to correct for this by encoding everything into unicode values before putting them in the dictionary that was to be added to the row. However this doesn't work. Any other ideas for formatting these values so that csv reader and dictreader can read them?

Comment: Which line gets the error?

Comment: `str(x[k])` seems very strange... if `x[k]` is unicode outside of the ascii range you will get the error.

Comment: line 14. the csvwriter.writerow part

Comment: str is used so that it works when the fields contain boolean values.

Comment: Can the fields contain unicode values? `unicode(x[k]).encode('utf-8')` could be the better option.... unless the strings are already utf-8 in which case you'll just double encode it.

Comment: weird. so that worked.... except when I try it, it converts other values to null. I tried this: csvwriter.writerow( {k: x[k] if isinstance(x[k],unicode) else unicode(x[k]).encode('utf-8') for k in x})   but it defaults to the same error. Isn't the error popping up only when it encounters a non-unicode character?

Comment: Alternatively, use an encoding csv wrapper, as described by me in an earlier answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33996769/1554386, or use a Unicode drop in replacement: https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv

Answer (score 1):

`str(x[k]).encode('utf-8')` is the problem.

`str(x[k])` will convert a Unicode string to an byte string using the default `ascii` codec in Python 2:

```
>>> x = u'résumé'
>>> str(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Non-Unicode values, like booleans, will be converted to byte strings, but then Python will implicitly decode the byte string to a Unicode string before calling `.encode()`, because you can only encode Unicode strings.  This usually won't cause an error because most non-Unicode objects have an ASCII representation.  Here's an example where a custom object returns a non-ASCII `str()` representation:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...  def __str__(self):
...    return 'r\xc3\xa9sum\xc3\xa9'
...
>>> x=Test()
>>> str(x)
'r\xc3\xa9sum\xc3\xa9'
>>> str(x).encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Note the above was a decode error instead of an encode error.

If `str()` is only there to coerce booleans to a string, coerce it to a Unicode string instead:

```
unicode(x[k]).encode('utf-8')
```

Non-Unicode values will be converted to Unicode strings, which can then be correctly encoded, but Unicode strings will remain unchanged, so they will also be encoded correctly.

```
>>> x = True
>>> unicode(x)
u'True'
>>> unicode(x).encode('utf8')
'True'
>>> x = u'résumé'
>>> unicode(x).encode('utf8')
'r\xc3\xa9sum\xc3\xa9'
```

P.S. Python 3 does not do implicit encode/decode between byte and Unicode strings and makes these errors easier to spot.