# 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u503c'

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to do template replacing in a file using pyratemp module. It's working fine with general ascii and UTF-8 format files. But, my file format is :
"UTF-8 Unicode C program text, with CRLF line terminators"

I'm having some variable in sql to replace. So, I'm processing using pyratemp module as followed.

```
import pyratemp
data_hash = {}
data_hash['tab_name'] = 'svm_table'
sourceFile = "sample.sql"
temp_sql = pyratemp.Template(filename=sourceFile, data=data_hash, encoding='utf-8')
```

Running the script:

```
python template_proc.py
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "template_proc.py", line 11, in 
>       print temp_sql
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u503c' in position 196: ordinal not in range(128)

Can any-one suggest me the solution to do it.

Comment: In which environment do you run the script - cmd, text editor, ...?

Comment: Running through command-line. on Suse-release 11 linux agent.

Comment: have look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010559/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xfa-in-position-42

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Python2. Reading unicode characters with Python2 is difficult, I will suggest you try this
`...
temp_sql = pyratemp.Template(filename=sourceFile, data=data_hash, encoding='utf-8')
encoded_temp_sql=temp_sql.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')`

You can see [Python HowTo](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more on how Python2 reads UNICODE characters