# Python/pandas: How to properly read csv file with Cyrillic text with encoding 'cp1252'?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding

I am trying to read the csv file containing the information about the bills/issues voted by the Ukrainian parliament into a pandas dataframe. The csv file contains the column 'name_question' that has the titles of the bills/issues in Ukrainian language. I read it into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://data.rada.gov.ua/ogd/zal/ppz/skl9/plenary_agenda-skl9.csv'
bills = pd.read_csv(url)
bills.head()
```

And I got this result. It seems that all Cyrillic characters are replaced with '?':

|  | date_agenda | id_question | number_question | init_question | name_question |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-08-29 | 201908291 | 0 | 0 | ?????????????????? ???????????????????????????... |
| 1 | 2019-08-29 | 201908292 | 0 | 0 | ?????????????????????????????????? |
| 2 | 2019-08-29 | 201908293 | 0 | 0 | ??????????????????????????????????????????'???... |
| 3 | 2019-08-29 | 201908294 | 0 | 0 | ????????,????????????????????????????????? |
| 4 | 2019-08-29 | 201908295 | 1001 | ? | ??????????????????????????????????????????????... |

I checked the encoding of the csv file, after downloading it and using [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648848/16772424). The output was as follows:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\dryingmouth\\data\\bills\\plenary_agenda-skl9.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>
```

I then edited the code to specify the encoding as a parameter of the read_csv() function:

```
bills = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='cp1251')
bills.head()
```

But the output was the same. What can I do to correctly display the Cyrillic (Ukrainian) characters in the dataframe created from this csv file?

Comment: I saved the csv to disk but it seems that the document contains literal `?` characters. It seems the csv is corrupted at the source.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33996769/14310038
This might help you, try this one,
Do reply back if working

Comment: Looks like the csv file is indeed corrupted, so I can't extract anything meaningful from it.